# Is there way to get Mysql table with column name changed, while not knowing the Column name but index?

Tags: mysql

Tough to say it in word. So here's an example

```
| Variable_name            | Value      |
+--------------------------+------------+
| Aborted_clients          |    0       |
| Aborted_connects         |    0       |
| Bytes_received           | 155372598  |
```

if there's a table like this, is there where to see exact same table but column name changed without knowing the column names?

So for example, let's say I want to see above table with different column names.
If I know the column names, it could be done by some kind of like

```
Select VARIABLE_NAME as var_name, VALUE as val .....
```

which will give us

```
| var_name                 | val        |
+--------------------------+------------+
| Aborted_clients          | 0          |
| Aborted_connects         | 0          |
| Bytes_received           | 155372598  |
```

I'm wondering if this could be done without knowing the column names.

Comment: When you write "Variable_name" and "Value", do you mean column name? Also, index has a special meaning in databases. They're used to find rows in a table faster then scanning the entire table. So what do you mean by "index"?

Comment: I can't think of a scenario where you wouldn't know a column name in a table, especially when there is a `describe table-name` command in sql.